# Get memberOf properties for child domain user from root domain GC

Tags: windows, active-directory, garbage-collection

I have a parent domain "parent.com" and a child domain "child.parent.com". User A belongs to the parent domain and user B belongs to the child domain.

I connect to the GC of the parent domain by using ADSI, and find that I cannot see the memberOf property of user B. But I can see the memberOf property of user A.

Could anyone tell me why? Or how could I get this property of user B in the parent domain GC?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have any code related to problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memberOf is a backlink attribute, so you have to connect to the child domain to make a DC in this child domain evaluate the attribute.